# in_array find out what position it was in?

Tags: php

Hi i have some arrays built up which have similar values such as:

```
$gamename = array("Name One", "Name Two", "Name Three");
$releasenumbers = array("1001", "1002", "1003");
```

Im Using in_array to find the numbers on a website. That part works fine it picks up the number for example if im searching for 1003 which is 3rd value in the array i want to return the 3rd value in the $gamename array too.

Is there a way to track what position the in_array value is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) instead. It’ll search the array for a given value and return the corresponding key if successful. For example, `array_search(1003, $releasenumbers)` will return the key `2` and therefore `$gamename[array_search(1003, $releasenumbers)]` will return `Name Three`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) instead of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to get the key of the found element.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the following is more efficient:

```
$merged = array_combine($releasenumbers,$gamename);
if( isset($merged[1003])) echo $merged[1003];
else "Not found!";
```